# Downloading a Word Document from a website and Chrome is abbreviating the name

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-word

In my work I am always downloading Word documents from a website.  Today it started acting strange.  The file name is Physical_Letter_accelevant.doc, but when the Save As window pops up it is abbreviating the file to Phsyical_Letter_A.doc.  It never did this before today and I need it to give me the full file name. Here is a screen shot:

[image: screen shot issue]

Comment: I can normally use the file name as downloaded. Try a different browser. Edge works well for me

Comment: Thanks.  Only use Chrome.  Didn't do this yesterday, so will keep searching for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is noting wrong with your browser. The issue is due to the way HTML works. The *name* of a link shown in the browser and the *actual location* to which the link points are two different things.

Here's an example: [George_Washington.jpg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Abraham_Lincoln.jpg). Despite appearing to be a reference to one file, the actual link is to one with a different name.

The name of the document on the file system of the web site is *Phsyical_Letter_A.doc* However, the *label* you see on-screen is *Physical_Letter_accelevant.doc*.

You can either request that the inconsistency be **fixed on the web site**, or you can download the file to another folder, to avoid overwriting a file with similar name, and then **rename it** as you wish. You can right-click on the name *displayed in the browser* to copy the label, then paste it over the mislabeled downloaded filename (<kbd>F2</kbd> to rename a file in Windows and Ubuntu).